# Problems displaying a PDF from a Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, servlets

I tried to display a PDF on my HTML page but it is shown.
My servlet code:

```java
try {
    String text = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
    Document document = new Document();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph(text));
    document.close();

    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(baos.size());
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    baos.writeTo(os);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
}
catch(DocumentException e) {
    throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
}
```

HTML code:

```java
<object id="mypdfobject" type="application/pdf" style="background-color: orange;color: black">
</object>
```

JavaScript Code:

```java
$.post("../paymailcontroller?uid="+uId,function(pdata){     
         var objectPDF = document.getElementById("mypdfobject");
         objectPDF.data=pdata;
    });
```

The browser I am using is Google chrome. If I call the page there is no PDF and I have no idea where to look for.

How can I display the created pdf in any browser?

The current output is like this, which is basically the raw PDF:

> %PDF-1.4 %���� 2 0 obj <>stream x�+�r �26S�00SI�2P�5�1���BҸ4>>>/Parent 3 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]>> endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 3 0 obj <> endobj 5 0 obj <> endobj 6 0 obj <> endobj xref 0 7 0000000000 65535 f 0000000333 00000 n 0000000015 00000 n 0000000421 00000 n 0000000176 00000 n 0000000484 00000 n 0000000529 00000 n trailer <]/Root 5 0 R/Size 7>> startxref 659 %%EOF

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the content disposition. There are two possibilities:

(1) Show the PDF within the browser

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + filename + "\";");
```

(2) Open a download to download the document

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\";");
```

Update: 
I think your JScript is not right. E.g. do it like this:

```
$("#" + this.divId).append('<object id="' + this.pdfObjectId + '" data="' + yourserver + path + file+'" type="application/pdf" width="768" height="1024"></object>');
```

For the rest of the parameters we set the following options:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
response.setHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

Comment: As you said I've tried both ways @Lonzak. unfortunately no difference same result is showing. Am I doing any mistake at Front-End side??

Comment: Yes I bet your JS is not right. Did you try first without JavaScript? Try to open a new URL in a new browser: window.open("http://.../yourPDF?name=name&...");

Comment: Actually I have one JSP page on that page itself I wanted to display pdf but due to that encoded result I have transferred my control to new HTML page with same like window.open and in this page only I have used that $.get(); method to get the generated PDF from servlet but in the HTML page also same result is showing which I have submitted output in question part.

Comment: Within your jscript you did not set the mimetype. Try to adapt the jscript example i gave you. If you see the raw PDF than this is usually a sign that either the content-type or the content-disposition is not correctly set

Comment: Could you please tell me what should I enter here in replace with (yourserver + path + file) ??

Comment: In the data attribute you have to add the URL to the PDF.  (cp. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp)

Comment: I did this with object, embed and div tag but only in div tag the pdf data is displaying in some encoded format and in other attributes nothing was displayed.

Comment: Suffering with same problem again, not getting the solution. need help!

Comment: I would suggest that you completely remove the JavaScript part. Showing a PDF directly in the browser (or offering a PDF download) is possible. So I would start there...